# Drawing Multiple Lines in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, line

Up until now, I've been using loops to add line elements to a D3 visualization, but this doesn't seem in the spirit of the API.

Let's say I have got some data,

```
var data = {time: 1, value: 2, value2: 5, value3: 3,value4: 2},
           {time: 2, value: 4, value2: 9, value3: 2,value4: 4},
           {time: 3, value: 8, value2:12, value3: 2,value4:15}]);
```

I'd like four lines, with time as the X for all 4.

I can do something like this:

```
var l = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d){return xScale(d[keys[0]]);})
        .y(function(d,i){
            return yScale(d[keys[1]]);})
        .interpolate("basis");
var l2 = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d){return xScale(d[keys[0]]);})
        .y(function(d,i){
            return yScale(d[keys[2]]);})
        .interpolate("basis");
var l3 = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d){return xScale(d[keys[0]]);})
        .y(function(d,i){
            return yScale(d[keys[3]]);})
        .interpolate("basis");  
var l4 = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d){return xScale(d[keys[0]]);})
        .y(function(d,i){
            return yScale(d[keys[4]]);})
        .interpolate("basis");
```

And then add these one by one (or by a loop).

```
var line1 = group.selectAll("path.path1")
        .attr("d",l(data));
var line2 = group.selectAll("path.path2")
        .attr("d",l2(data));
var line3 = group.selectAll("path.path3")
        .attr("d",l3(data));
var line4 = group.selectAll("path.path4")
        .attr("d",l4(data));
```

Is there a better more general way of adding these paths?

Answer (score 81):

Yes. First I would restructure your data for easier iteration, like this:

```
var series = [
  [{time: 1, value: 2}, {time: 2, value: 4}, {time: 3, value: 8}],
  [{time: 1, value: 5}, {time: 2, value: 9}, {time: 3, value: 12}],
  [{time: 1, value: 3}, {time: 2, value: 2}, {time: 3, value: 2}],
  [{time: 1, value: 2}, {time: 2, value: 4}, {time: 3, value: 15}]
];
```

Now you need just a single generic line:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });
```

And, you can then add all of the path elements in one go:

```
group.selectAll(".line")
    .data(series)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

If you want to make the data structure format smaller, you could also extract the times into a separate array, and then use a 2D array for the values. That would look like this:

```
var times = [1, 2, 3];

var values = [
  [2, 4, 8],
  [5, 9, 12],
  [3, 2, 2],
  [2, 4, 15]
];
```

Since the matrix doesn't include the time value, you need to look it up from the x-accessor of the line generator. On the other hand, the y-accessor is simplified since you can pass the matrix value directly to the y-scale:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(times[i]); })
    .y(y);
```

Creating the elements stays the same:

```
group.selectAll(".line")
    .data(values)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

Comment: Mike, I used your example here to make some progress on multiple lines but how do you transitions? Wondering if you could eyeball this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404283/d3-js-transform-transition-multiple-lines -- Thanks!

Comment: x(d.time); seems to be incorrect - there is no particular function for this; it only works if you change it to simply d.time. The same for the corresponding y.

Comment: `x` and `y` refer to scales, which you should define before using.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is supposed to be directly usable, but at the moment, this code cannot be dropped into one of the example files and work. At least not for a newbie like me.

Comment: This seems like an elegant solution--it just doesn't work for me. I have an array of x-axis years: ["2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011"] and a 2D array of graduation rates: [["45.9%","42.8%","51.0%","53.3%","47.1%","56.2%","54.5%","N/A","46.2%","51.7%"],["50.0%","30.8%","22.2%","27.8%","14.8%","43.8%","25.0%","N/A","25.0%","40.0%"]] ..and I can't get a line to draw with that exact code. (okay, had to add defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d); })) Tried parsing these numbers as floats too. Spent hours this weekend on this. Powerful! Simple! Baffling!

Comment: Is this complete? Where is `group.selectAll` coming from, I don't see the group object defined.

Comment: group refers to an svg group, which you should define prior to appending the paths.

Comment: What are functions x and y? There are undefined.

Comment: .interpolate('basis') is not explained anywhere I can find. It also gives my code an error `Property 'interpolate' does not exist on type 'Line<[number, number]>'`