# d3.js - transform & transition, multiple lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, set

I have followed the instructions at: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/ for creating and animating single graphs with single lines.

And, figured out how to create multiple lines in a graph: [Drawing Multiple Lines in D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689498/drawing-multiple-lines-in-d3-js)

**Main Issue:** I am having a hard time transitioning multiple lines after I shift & push in new data into my data array.

I create the ***N*** lines with: (time: epoch time, steps forward)

```
var seriesData = [[{time:1335972631000, value:23}, {time:1335972631500, value:42},...],
                  [{time:1335972631000, value:45}, {time:1335972631500, value:13},...],
                  [{time:1335972631000, value:33}, {time:1335972631500, value:23},...}],
                  [...],[...],...
                  ];

var seriesColors = ['red', 'green', 'blue',...];

line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate(interpolation)
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

graphGroup.selectAll(".line")
        .data(seriesData)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line)
            .style('stroke', function(d, i) { return seriesColors[i]; })
            .style('stroke-width', 1)
            .style('fill', 'none');
```

And am trying to update ***N*** lines with a Javascript setInterval(...) calling a method with:

```
graph.selectAll("path")
    .data(seriesData)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(1) + ")")
    .attr("d", line)
      .transition()
    .ease("linear")
    .duration(transitionDelay)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ")");
```

It can draw the initial set perfectly, but as soon as I update the data array, the lines just disappear.

---

***UPDATE 01***

I realized that I am using epoch time values in the x (xAxis shows date:time) as my example would probably work if I used the illustrative seriesData above.

The problem was the "transform", "translate" using x(1), x(0) was returning huge numbers, way *larger* than my graph needed to be transitioned.

I modified the *update* ***N*** lines method (above) to use a manual approach:

**New Issue:**
Now the graph moves left correctly, but the lines/graph *pops* back to the right, each setInterval update executes.

It's push/shift'ing the seriesData array correctly but it doesn't keep scrolling to the left to show the new data that IS actually being drawn.

```
graph.selectAll("path")
        .data(seriesData)
        .attr("d", line)
        .attr("transform", null)
          .transition()
        .ease("linear")
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("transform", "translate(-200)");
```

Another reference that I have used is this: http://bl.ocks.org/1148374

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am starting to think this has to do with my use of d3.time.scale()... for the x vs. d3.scale.linear()...?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If so please post your solution.

Comment: I ended up making three separate graph's with a single line each. Then I use CSS to stack the graph ID's on top of each other. It was easier to manage and to reuse. Especially if I wanted it to be smooth..

Answer (score 1):

One thing that jumps out at me as a possibility for error is the data calls that are used, the initial is

```
.data(seriesData)
```

the update uses

```
.data([seriesData])
```

which may cause issues, but its hard to tell without seeing the rest of what is going on, can you perhaps put it on jsfiddle?

Comment: Excellent observation, but it's doesn't fix the update issue.

Comment: So I presume this means when changing the second data call to match the first, nothing changes? - there are certainly cases where you would want to pass all of your data as a single element array, but this doesn't seem to be one of those, from what I can tell.  I'm afraid I cannot help much more without seeing more of the code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately I cannot share the entire code block. The issue is coming from having epoch time values in the x.. So, the translation in the update will not work with x(1)... x(0). I'm going to update the question now.