# D3 transitions on more than 1 svg element

Tags: graph, d3.js, transition

I am new to D3 and trying to learn a few basics. I've been using the D3 tips and Tricks book and tried to adapt a line graph to get a couple of lines into it which both transition. The basic idea is that Line A starts off with Data A, Line B with Data B. Then on clicking a button, Line A transitions to Data C and Line B to Data D.

The line graph is an over time graph so I've set the x axis to be a time axis.

Here's the code I'm using (cut down a bit)

```
      // Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)                          
.orient("bottom").ticks(10);            
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)                      
.orient("left").ticks(5);                               

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()                               
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })                   
.y(function(d) { return y(d.number); });                    

// Define the line
var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()                              
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })                   
.y(function(d) { return y(d.number2); });                   

// Define the line
var valueline3 = d3.svg.line()                              
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })                   
.y(function(d) { return y(d.number3); });                   

// Define the line
var valueline4 = d3.svg.line()                              
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })                   
.y(function(d) { return y(d.number4); });                   

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")                                 
.append("svg")                                          
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)  
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")                                            
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); 
// Get the data
d3.tsv("data/data3.tsv", function(error, data) {                
d.date = parseDate(d.date);                         
d.number = +d.number;                               
d.number2 = +d.number2; 
d.number3 = +d.number3; 
d.number4 = +d.number4; 
d.number5 = +d.number5; 
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));      
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.number4; })]); 

// Add the  path.
svg.append("path")                                  
.attr("d", valueline(data));    

    //Add the transition for the first line                 
d3.select("p2")
.on("click", function() {
svg.select("path")
.data(data)
.transition()
.delay(function(d, i) {
return i / 40 * 1000;
})
.duration(1500)                         
.attr("d", valueline3(data));
}) ;



// Add the second path.
svg.append("path")                                                                  
    .attr("d", valueline2(data))    

//Add the transition for the second line        
d3.select("p3")
            .on("click", function() {
                svg.select("path")
                   .data(data)
                   .transition()
                   .delay(function(d, i) {
                       return i / 40 * 1000;
                   })
                   .duration(1500)      
                    .attr("d", valueline4(data));


                   })
```

The problem is that oth transitions end up applying to the first line, with the second one static What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're calling `svg.select("path")` in the click handler. This will select the first path in the SVG -- that is, both times the same path (the one you appended first) will be selected and changed.

The way to mitigate this would be to reference `this` in the click handler that is attached to a specific path, i.e. replace

```
svg.select("path")
```

with

```
d3.select(this)
```

Some general comments. The way you're selecting the paths is by calling `d3.select("p2")`. This is almost certainly not what you want -- this is selecting a DOM element with that name. If you've assigned an ID to the respective path, use `d3.select("#p2")`, if you've assigned a class use `d3.select(".p2")`.

You also don't need to reference `data` twice when you're creating the path provided you pass it as an array. That is, instead of

```
svg.select("path").data(data)                        
   .attr("d", valueline3(data));
```

you can do

```
svg.select("path").data([data])                        
   .attr("d", valueline3);
```

which removes some redundancy.

And finally, the D3 way would be to use the same line generator and pass in different data arrays for the different lines. Instead of having four different line generators, you would simply extract your original data into four different arrays and use those. You can also do it altogether with just a single call. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689498/drawing-multiple-lines-in-d3-js) has some more information.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is superbly helpful, both the main point and the subsequent tidying up points. Ta!

Comment: Oh hang on I think I've confused things a bit. This isn't working for me and I think I know why. The p2 p3 etc are bits of text elsewhere, not the lines themselves. So when I use "this" that refers to the text, right? Rather than the line. So this won't update the line as it stands?

Comment: The `this` in the handler refers to the selected DOM element. And it should be `d3.select(this)` instead of `svg.select(this)` in the answer -- my bad, I'll fix it.

Comment: Hey thanks again. I actually fixed it in a roundabout way using your other advice - I gave the lines an id and then referred to the id. So many ways to skin a cat in d3, it seems...

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well. The advantage of doing something in a handler function is that you get direct access to the DOM element in `this`, which can make things easier -- any other way is fine as well though.