# Drawing a waveform with D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm very new to d3 and finding it a bit overwhelming.  I have an array of arrays containing y1 and y2 for each sample.

```
waveformData = [[79, 140], [67, 145], [70, 152], ..... ]
```

Currently I'm drawing it like so:

```
waveformData.forEach(function(data,i){
    svg.append("line")
        .attr('y1', data[0])
        .attr('y2', data[1])
        .attr('x1', i +0.5)
        .attr('x2', i +0.5)
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr("stroke", "green");
}
```

[image: waveform]

It works but I'm not doing it in the 'spirit' of d3.  Could someone explain how to use d3 as it was intended for something like this?

Comment: Consider the answer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689498/drawing-multiple-lines-in-d3-js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The D3 way would be:

```
svg.selectAll('line')
  .data(waveformData)
.enter().append('line')
  .attr('y1', function(d) { return d[0]; })
  .attr('y2', function(d) { return d[1]; })
  .attr('x1', function(d, i) { return i +0.5; })
  .attr('x2', function(d, i) { return i +0.5; })
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr("stroke", "green");
```

Comment: You may want to use an [area chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195) instead.