# Adding multiple lines to chart d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to add multiple data sets to my plot. I am using the following question as a reference; [Drawing Multiple Lines in D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689498/drawing-multiple-lines-in-d3-js). Unfortunately it does not seem to work in my case, most likely I am doing something wrong but I do not seem to find my failure unfortunately.

The relevant part of the code is located in the `redraw` function. There I create the two data sets and add them to the series. After that I try to plot the series as is described in the reference.

Hopefully someone can help me with this :-)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>MPERT</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
  
rect {
    fill: transparent;
}
  
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
  
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
}
  
.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
  
.grid path {
    stroke-width: 0;
}

#slider-pertmin, #slider-pertmode, #slider-pertmax, #slider-pertshape {
 float: right;
 width: 120px;
 margin: 7px;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal {
 height: 8px;
 width: 200px;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
 height: 15px;
 width: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
}

#plot {
  background-color:#f9f9f9;
 border:solid 1px #ddd;
 padding:10px;
  width:250px;
}
 
#plotOptions {
 background-color:#f9f9f9;
 border:solid 1px #ddd;
 padding:10px;
}
 
.block label { 
 display: inline-block; 
 width: 60px; 
 text-align: right; 
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 // Log-gamma function
 gammaln = function gammaln(x)
 {
  var cof = [ 76.18009172947146,  -86.50532032941677,      24.01409824083091,
        -1.231739572450155,   0.1208650973866179e-2, -0.5395239384953e-5];

  var j = 0;
  var ser = 1.000000000190015;
  var xx, y, tmp;

  tmp = (y = xx = x) + 5.5;
  tmp -= (xx + 0.5) * Math.log(tmp);

  for (; j < 6; j++)
   ser += cof[j] / ++y;

  return Math.log(2.5066282746310005 * ser / xx) - tmp;
 };
 
 // Gamma function
 gammafn = function gammafn(x) 
 {
  var p = [    -1.716185138865495,    24.76565080557592,   -379.80425647094563,
        629.3311553128184,     866.9662027904133,  -31451.272968848367,
        -36144.413418691176,    66456.14382024054];

  var q = [    -30.8402300119739,     315.35062697960416, -1015.1563674902192,
       -3107.771671572311,    22538.118420980151,    4755.8462775278811,
     -134659.9598649693,    -115132.2596755535];
   
  var fact = false,
   n = 0,
   xden = 0,
   xnum = 0,
   y = x,
   i, 
   z, 
   yi, 
   res, 
   sum, 
   ysq;

  if (y <= 0) {
   res = y % 1 + 3.6e-16;
   
   if (res) {
    fact = (!(y & 1) ? 1 : -1) * Math.PI / Math.sin(Math.PI * res);
    y = 1 - y;
   } else
    return Infinity;
  }

  yi = y;

  if (y < 1)
   z = y++;
  else
   z = (y -= n = (y | 0) - 1) - 1;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
   xnum = (xnum + p[i]) * z;
   xden = xden * z + q[i];
  }

  res = xnum / xden + 1;

  if (yi < y)
   res /= yi;
  else if (yi > y) {
   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    res *= y;
    y++;
   }
  }

  if (fact)
   res = fact / res;

  return res;
 };

 // Beta function
 betafn = function betafn(x,y) 
 {
  // ensure arguments are positive
  if (x <= 0 || y <= 0)
   return undefined;

  // make sure x + y doesn't exceed the upper limit of usable values
  return (x + y > 170)
   ? Math.exp(betaln(x, y))
   : gammafn(x) * gammafn(y) / gammafn(x + y);
 };
 
 // Natural logarithm of Beta function
 betaln = function betaln(x, y) 
 {
  return gammaln(x) + gammaln(y) - gammaln(x + y);
 };
 
 $(function() {
  $("#slider-pertmin").slider({
   range: "min",
   value: 1,
   min: 1,
   max: 20,
   step: 0.1,
   slide: function(event,ui) {
    if (ui.value > $("#slider-pertmode").slider("value")) {
     $("#pertmin").val($("#slider-pertmode").slider("value") - 0.1);
     $("#slider-pertmin").slider("value",$("#slider-pertmode").slider("value") - 0.1)
    } else
     $("#pertmin").val(ui.value);

    redraw(); 
   },
   change: function(event,ui) {
     $("#slider-pertmin").slider("value",$("#pertmin").val());
   }
  });

  $("#slider-pertmode").slider({
   range: "min",
   value: 3,
   min: 1,
   max: 20,
   step: 0.1,
   slide: function(event,ui) {
    if (ui.value < $("#slider-pertmin").slider("value")) {
     $("#pertmode").val($("#slider-pertmin").slider("value") + 0.1);
     $("#slider-pertmode").slider("value",$("#slider-pertmin").slider("value") + 0.1);
    } else if (ui.value > $("#slider-pertmax").slider("value")) {
     $("#pertmode").val($("#slider-pertmax").slider("value") - 0.1);
     $("#slider-pertmode").slider("value",$("#slider-pertmax").slider("value") - 0.1);
    } else
     $("#pertmode").val(ui.value);

    redraw();
   },
   change: function(event,ui) {
     $("#slider-pertmode").slider("value",$("#pertmode").val());
   }
  });

  $("#slider-pertmax").slider({
   range: "min",
   value: 6,
   min: 1,
   max: 20,
   step: 0.1,
   slide: function(event,ui) {
    if (ui.value < $("#slider-pertmode").slider("value")) {
     $("#pertmax").val($("#slider-pertmode").slider("value") + 0.1);
     $("#slider-pertmax").slider("value",$("#slider-pertmode").slider("value") + 0.1);
    } else
     $("#pertmax").val(ui.value);

    redraw();
   },
   change: function(event,ui) {
        $("#slider-pertmax").slider("value",$("#pertmax").val());
   }
  });
  
  $("#slider-pertshape").slider({
   range: "min",
   value: 6,
   min: 1,
   max: 20,
   step: 0.1,
   slide: function(event,ui) {
    $("#pertshape").val($("#slider-pertshape").slider("value"));
   },
   change: function(event,ui) {
    $("#slider-pertshape").slider("value",$("#pertshape").val());
   }
  });

  $("#pertmin").val($("#slider-pertmin").slider("value"));
  $("#pertmode").val($("#slider-pertmode").slider("value"));
  $("#pertmax").val($("#slider-pertmax").slider("value"));
  $("#pertshape").val($("#slider-pertshape").slider("value"));
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="plot"></div>
<div id="plotOptions" class="ui-widget" style="width:250px">
 <div class="block"> 
  <label for="pertmin">min:</label> <input type="value" id="pertmin" style="border:none; background: transparent; width:40px;" />
  <div class="ui-slider" id="slider-pertmin" />
 </div>
 <div class="block"> 
  <label for="pertmode">mode:</label> <input type="value" id="pertmode" style="border:none; background: transparent; width:40px;" />
  <div class="ui-slider" id="slider-pertmode" />
 </div>
 <div class="block">
  <label for="pertmax">max:</label> <input type="value" id="pertmax" style="border:none; background: transparent; width:40px;" />
  <div class="ui-slider" id="slider-pertmax" />
 </div>
 <div class="block">
  <label for="pertshape">shape:</label> <input type="value" id="pertshape" style="border:none; background: transparent; width:40px;" />
  <div class="ui-slider" id="slider-pertshape" />
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var pert = {
  min: 2,
  mode: 4,
  max: 9
 };

 var mpert = {
  shape: 0.5
 };

 var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 35,
        left: 50
     },
  width = 250 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([pert.min, pert.max])
  .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 1])
  .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(5)
  .innerTickSize(-6)
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .tickPadding(7);

    var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .innerTickSize(-6)
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .tickPadding(7);

    var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("top")
  .ticks(5)
  .innerTickSize(-6)
  .tickPadding(-20)
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .tickFormat("");

    var yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .innerTickSize(6)
  .tickPadding(-20)
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .tickFormat("");

    var xGrid = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickSize(-height, -height, 0)
  .tickFormat("");

    var yGrid = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, -width, 0)
  .tickFormat("");
 
 var color = d3.scale.category10();
 
    var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d,i) {
   return x(d.x);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
   return y(d.y);
  })
  .interpolate("linear");
   
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(x)
  .y(y)
  .scaleExtent([1, 1])
  .on("zoom",redraw);
      
    var svg = d3.select("#plot").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(zoom);
   
    // Add x grid
    svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x grid")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xGrid);

    // Add y grid
    svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y grid")
  .call(yGrid);

    svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x1 axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis1);

    svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y1 axis")
  .call(yAxis1);

    /* append additional X axis */
    svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x2 axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + [0, 0] + ")")
  .call(xAxis2);

    /* append additional y axis */
    svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y2 axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + [width, 0] + ")")
  .call(yAxis2);

    // Add x axis label  
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("font-size","15")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("x axis");

    // Add y axis label
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y",0 - margin.left)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("font-size","15")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("y axis");

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
      
    svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")

    function redraw() {
  pert.min   = $("#slider-pertmin").slider("value");
  pert.mode  = $("#slider-pertmode").slider("value");
  pert.max   = $("#slider-pertmax").slider("value");
  pert.mu    = (pert.min + 4*pert.mode + pert.max)/6;
  pert.a1    = 6*(pert.mu - pert.min) / (pert.max - pert.min);
  pert.a2    = 6*(pert.max - pert.mu) / (pert.max - pert.min);
  pert.beta  = betafn(pert.a1,pert.a2);
  mpert.a1   = 1 + mpert.shape * (pert.mode - pert.min) / (pert.max - pert.min)
  mpert.a2   = 1 + mpert.shape * (pert.max - pert.mode) / (pert.max - pert.min)
  mpert.beta = betafn(mpert.a1,mpert.a2);
  
  x.domain([pert.min, pert.max]);
 
  svg.select(".x1.axis").call(xAxis1);
  svg.select(".y1.axis").call(yAxis1);
  svg.select(".x2.axis").call(xAxis2);
  svg.select(".y2.axis").call(yAxis2);
  svg.select(".x.grid").call(xGrid);
  svg.select(".y.grid").call(yGrid);
  
  var data1 = [];
  var data2 = [];
  var series = [];
  
  for (var k = pert.min; k < pert.max; k += 0.1) {
   data1.push({ 
    x: k,
    y: (1/pert.beta)*(Math.pow(k - pert.min,pert.a1 - 1) * 
          Math.pow(pert.max - k,pert.a2 - 1)) /
          Math.pow(pert.max - pert.min,pert.a1 + pert.a2 - 1)
   })

   data2.push({
    x: k,
    y: (1/mpert.beta)*(Math.pow(k - pert.min,mpert.a1 - 1) * 
           Math.pow(pert.max - k,mpert.a2 - 1)) /
           Math.pow(pert.max - pert.min,mpert.a1 + mpert.a2 - 1)
   });
  }

  series.push(data1);
  series.push(data2);

  d3.selectAll(".line")
   .data(series)
   .enter().append("path")
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("d", line);
 }

 $(function() {
  redraw();
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a quick observation, should your series.push statements be moved outside the for loop?

Comment: As @AnthonyPatton, `series.push` should be outside of loop, after that you need a [nested selection](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/), something like `svg.selectAll(".series").data(series).enter().append('g').attr('class', 'series').selectAll('.line').data(function(d){ return d; }).enter().append('path').attr('class','line').attr('d', line);`

Comment: @Mark that does not seem anything like the solution provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689498/drawing-multiple-lines-in-d3-js which I use as reference...?

Comment: @WG-, my bad, should have looked at that question.  Hard to argue with the inventor of the framework :)  In this case you don't need a nested selection.  If you move series.push outside of the loop, the only thing you have wrong is small typo `d3.selectAll` should be `svg.selectAll`: http://plnkr.co/edit/MAxPaj9vmm2dwR9EtZGg?p=preview

Comment: @Mark your solution seems to introduce a bug? Because when I now try to change the mode the plot does not change :-(

Comment: @WG-, that's actually there in your code above, you are getting a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, seems like you might have some infinite recursion going on.

Comment: @WG-, actually, see this one:  http://plnkr.co/edit/MAxPaj9vmm2dwR9EtZGg?p=preview, I was only handling the enter, not the update.  You still get the callstack error, though.