# d3: drawing a multi-line line graph from a 2d array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a multi-line line graph in d3, and then update it on every tick. The problem I'm experiencing is that I end up with either an error a graph with zero data. I found other answers here, but they're all either for a very old version of d3 or for more simple data than I have.

My data looks like this (simplified, obviously, but the structure is the same):

```
let data = [
  [{name: "a", val: 1}, {name: "b", val: 2}],
  [{name: "a", val: 2}, {name: "b", val: 3}],
  [{name: "a", val: 3}, {name: "b", val: 4}],
  [{name: "a", val: 4}, {name: "b", val: 5}],
]
```

I want two lines: one of the values of A per index and one of the values of B per index. [Other posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689498/drawing-multiple-lines-in-d3-js) have asked the same question, but for 3.0 of d3.

From this question, I extrapolated to the following:

```
let svg = ...
let g = svg.append("g")...

let line = d3.line()
    .x((d:any, i:number) => x(i))
    .y((d:any) => y(d.value))
```

```
g.selectAll(".line")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

This throws an error on every tick: `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,20Z"`, and I'm not too surprised, because TypeScript complains too:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Line<[number, number]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<SVGPathElement, GraphablePacketCount[], string | number | boolean | null>'.
    Types of parameters 'data' and 'datum' are incompatible.
```

Other stuff I tried:

```
for (const datum of data) {
    g.append("svg:line").data(datum)...
}
```

And a line-ified version of [d3's general update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218):

```
let lines = g.selectAll("line").data(data);
lines.enter().append(...);
```

which just leads to an empty graph. In this case, `console.log(lines.enter())` gives me the data, it just doesn't render.

What on earth do I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Your data array has `val` fields, but in line's y accessor you use `value`.

But even then, your issue is that you sliced your data by wrong dimension. You bind data to lines, and thus your each element in your data (outter) array should be data for a single line, and then inner array should be that line's points (because line generator accepts array of points). But you have it other way around, as you first go by-point first and only then differentiate the line.

You'll have to adapt your data, either by adjusting it at the source, or doing transformation before the binding. See example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // Feel free to change or delete any of the code you see in this editor!
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 300)
      .attr("height", 100);

    let data = [
      [{
        name: "a",
        val: 1
      }, {
        name: "b",
        val: 2
      }],
      [{
        name: "a",
        val: 2
      }, {
        name: "b",
        val: 3
      }],
      [{
        name: "a",
        val: 3
      }, {
        name: "b",
        val: 4
      }],
      [{
        name: "a",
        val: 4
      }, {
        name: "b",
        val: 5
      }],
    ];

    var byLineDataMap = data.reduce(function(lineData, point) {
      point.forEach(function(linePoint) {
        if (!lineData[linePoint.name])
          lineData[linePoint.name] = [];
        lineData[linePoint.name].push({
          val: linePoint.val
        });
      });
      return lineData;
    }, {});

    var byLineData = Object.entries(byLineDataMap);
    /*
            var byLineData = [
             ['a', [{val: 1}, ...]],
             ['b', [{val: 2}, ...]]
            ];
    */

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 4])
      .range([50, 250]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([1, 5])
      .range([80, 20]);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(['a', 'b'])
      .range(['red', 'blue']);

    var lineGen = d3.line()
      .x(function(d, i) {
        return x(i)
      })
      .y(function(d, i) {
        return y(d.val)
      });

    svg.selectAll('path')
      .data(byLineData)
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .style('stroke', function(d) {
        return color(d[0]);
      })
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        return lineGen(d[1]);
      });
  </script>
</body>
```