# Beginner d3.js user - How would one plot multiple paths from one JSON file?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I can't seem to figure out how to plot multiple paths from a single file. Any insight (even a link to go read a relevant article) would be much appreciated. Right now, I have the JSON file structured as such 
In other words, there is data for three paths comprised of (x,y) points in the file.

```
[[{"x":583.8843463788733,"y":500,"variance":19.7417285769381},{"x":567.4313561576101,"y":543.7493061749581,"variance":19.65391679344352},{"x":593.8706097672987,"y":504.9969033892481,"variance":19.671984434861272}],[{"x":583.8843463788733,"y":500,"variance":19.7417285769381},{"x":582.6338195389559,"y":493.2434916829899,"variance":19.67632856405124},{"x":571.4943464713781,"y":523.9430111778358,"variance":19.64233848555563},{"x":560.4820781617861,"y":527.7907462656625,"variance":19.589964023446342}],[{"x":583.8843463788733,"y":500,"variance":19.7417285769381},{"x":590.3648419549969,"y":536.6508758859135,"variance":19.645788784272792},{"x":592.0583326788998,"y":525.6438352182007,"variance":19.675558736878834},{"x":632.0065097396131,"y":547.709205638192,"variance":19.592090433908},{"x":583.0723553058078,"y":538.0471857868156,"variance":19.67866584637368}]]
```

I tried referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689498/drawing-multiple-lines-in-d3-js) but I don't think the situation described in that post is applicable...

Here are my questions...

1) Do I have the JSON file structured correctly? 
2) How do I plot all three paths? 
3) How would I plot them consecutively, with some delay?

Here is my code thus far:

```
function plot(x, y, nameFile){

  d3.json(nameFile).then(function(data){


    var svgHeight = window.innerHeight - 100;
    var svgWidth = window.innerWidth - 10;

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', svgWidth)
      .attr('height', svgHeight)


    var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });


    group.selectAll(".line")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);



  })
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read through my question.

Comment: With the proper scales, your code works (hardcoded domains here): https://jsfiddle.net/xroesj5d/. By the way, you're mixing D3 v3 syntax with v5: it should be `d3.line()`, not `d3.svg.line()`, and `curve`, not `interpolate`.

Comment: Gerardo - thank you! I'll make those edits and try again... out of curiosity, why does the code work only with scales? @GerardoFurtado

Comment: It works without scales, the thing is that you have scales in the line generator.